# I want to get list of available wifi devices by coronasdk

Tags: list, networking, wifi, coronasdk

now, i develop by coronasdk tools(www.coronasdk.com)

I want to get list of available wifi devices by coronasdk

how to do this?

program process

1)viewing intro

2)scan network(only wifi)

3)view wifi SSID List

4)select SSID

5)connect choosend SSID's device

6)get remote device file list in use JSON

...

help me plz

Answer (score 0):

[Autolan](http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/autolan) Should do it for you!
It is a pretty useful library for implementing multiplayer.